# Using wildcard in regex causes inefficient scanning

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file (size 7GB plus) filled with repeated lines as follows where 10.00 and 2.00 may differ each line:

```
startline money earned 10.00 "300 plus nums n words here" money start 2.00 more words
```

I want to obtain the values 10.00 and 2.00

My regex is as follows which works:

```
money earned ([0-9\.]+).*money start ([0-9\.]+)
```

But this is ridiculously inefficient. I took almost 30 mins to scan 1% of the text file! It seems the `.*` is causing this inefficiency. Thus I opted to get those values by using 2 separate regex lines as follows which works as well and a lot more efficient.

```
money earned ([0-9\.]+) //this is line 1 capturing 10.00
money start ([0-9\.]+)  //this is line 2 capturing 2.00
```

But this causes the **money earned (10.00)** to be captured first as its the first portion of each line and **money start (2.00)** ends up being second.

I want to reverse this and be able to capture **money start (2.00)** first for each line and **money earned (10.00)** as second. Is there any way I can reverse the regex to start from the back of the line and move to the front. Or, anyway I can overcome the inefficiency when scanning with a single line of regex?

Comment: Have you tried this regex? `money (?:earned|start) ([0-9\.]+)`

Comment: [mcve]?  Are you reading in the entire file as one 7GB string, or line at a time?  Does your string parsing allow `.` to match new lines?  You'll need to provide a bit more detail.

Comment: Are you compiling the `Pattern` once, and reusing it, or are you recreating it each time you read in a line?

Comment: @AJNeufeld One line at a time. When I do .* I am trying to skip through all the hundreds of lines and reach money start all on the same line. Those lines has some sorta sensitive data. I can't post them sorry.

Comment: We're not asking you to post sensitive data.  Take your code, strip it down to the bare minimum that reproduces your issue, and post that.  We can take the code, modify it to search for some similar data from our own 7GB log files, and verify the inefficiency, so we can determine what the bottleneck actually is, instead of just guessing.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I've not. Gonna try, might address the efficiency issue.  But that won't separate out the 2 figures. Everything will be captured as a single group won't it. 10.00, 2.00 10.00, 2.00 captured not knowing which is which.

Comment: @anubhava Its part of an internal framework. I have to use regex.

Comment: @JasSy, well your question is a bit unclear to me, check if you want something like this https://regex101.com/r/aB7hT8/1

Comment: Why on earth do you care about the order of the capture groups? The order is left to right as you define them. There's nothing you can do about that, and nothing you should want to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to pre-process your file before your java program takes over?

I created a 7.1 GB file using your example as a template. I then pre-processed it using grep to create an intermediary file that could then be more-easily processed by java.

```
time grep -Eo 'money (earned|start) \d+\.\d+' large_file.txt > results.txt

real    3m12.306s
user    3m7.701s
sys     0m3.222s
```

The `results.txt` file only took about three minutes to create, is only 168M, and is in the format of:

```
money earned 10.00
money start 2.00
money earned 10.00
money start 2.00 
money earned 10.00
money start 2.00
```

Comment: Did you try processing the file directly with Java first, to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
money earned ([0-9\.]+).*money start ([0-9\.]+)
                       ^^
```

There's your problem. This is a *greedy* match. That means that it starts matching *as much as possible* before backtracking and trying shorter matches to allow the rest of the regex to match. So if you have *a lot* of data, or very long lines (or even a very long string, depending on whether `.` may match line breaks), this may take a while. It also depends a bit on how your data looks like. If there is a lot of text coming after the last `money start` then it takes longer. If you have more than one `money start` in the line, everything but the last is skipped.

You could try using `.*?` instead, which is a *lazy* match, that is, it starts with as *little* as possible and extends it. In many cases this is much faster.